# Best Practices for winforms communications?

Tags: .net, winforms, oop, communication

I'm looking for some best practices for winforms communications in .NET .
How 2 different winforms send and receive data in oop style?

Comment: What kind of communication are you talking about? What type of data do you want to send/receive? This question is really too vague in its current state to answer.

Comment: Well, communication between a form and search form, communication between a form and another form which shows detail info.....

Answer (score 1):

As Cody said the question needs more details. Based on the only info you provided you can make use of simple events and pass information via **custom** `EventArgs` derived classes.